# How do you calculate the derivative of the multivariate normal CDF with respect to a correlation coefficient?

Tags: normal-distribution

How does one calculate the derivative of a multivariate normal CDF with respect to a given correlation coefficient?

I have started with the bivariate case but couldn't work it out.

Comment: Do you really mean CDF? Or do you rather mean PDF?

Comment: No, I really mean CDF! Differentiating the PDF would be easy. I have tried this for the bivariate case, by taking the derivative inside the integral and then differentiating the PDF. But then the algebra gets really hard when I try to solve the integral.

Comment: just a remak in the case where you do not know this: the cdf does not exist in closed form

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do or why (I'm not sure what it means to take a derivative "with respect to a given correlation coefficient")... can you explain?

Comment: The what is to calculate $dF(x)/d\rho_{ij}$, the why is to be able to learn the parameters of a product of Gaussian copulae by gradient ascent.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the answer to this.

There is a result,

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho_{ij}}f(x;0,\Sigma)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}f(x;0,\Sigma)$ ("A reduction formula for normal multivariate integrals", Plackett 1954).

So using this result by exchanging the integral and derivative, we just need to be able to differentiate a normal CDF with respect to two of the variables. We can do this by first applying the fundamental theorem of calculus, then conditioning on the two variables,

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho_{ij}}F(x;0,\Sigma)=f(x_i,x_j;0,\Sigma_{ij})F(x-\{x_i,x_j\}\ |\ x_i,x_j)$